# Regex for extracting P values from a PDF

Tags: r, regex

I'm doing a small personal project where I'm trying to extract the p values in a series of psychology papers.

I have a long string that looks a little like this:

"We failed to reject the null in the xyz condition (t = (271), p = 0.56), but found significant results in the condition (t = (271), p < 0.02)"

Using the str_extract_all() function in R, I wanted to identify string matches that start with "p =" OR "p <" and end in ")". The desired output would be a vector/list that looks like: c("p = 0.56", "p < 0.02").

My current attempt looks like this:

```
str_extract_all(text, "(?<=`p <`).(?=\\))")
```

and the output is an empty list:

[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

I haven't bothered to work out the "or" logic for "p <" and "p =", because I can't get either on their own to work. I appreciate any assistance :)

Comment: Please format code related parts of your post, so it looks more readable

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(c, 'p\\s?[=<>]\\s?0\\.\\d{1,4}'))
[1] "p = 0.56" "p < 0.02"
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you